# Let $z=x+iy$ and $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$ be the map function $f(x,y)=f(z)=z^2=(x^2-y^2, 2xy)\in\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $z=x+iy$ and $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$ be the map function  $f(x,y)=f(z)=z^2=(x^2-y^2, 2xy)\in\mathbb{R^2}$. Let $Df(0)$ denote the derivative of f at a. Which of the following are true?

A. $Df(a)h=2ah, where \;a=a_1+ia_2\; h=h_1+ih_2$

B. $(Df)(a)=\left( \begin{array}_
a_1&-a_2\\
a_2& a_1\end{array} \right), a=(a_1,a_2)\in\mathbb{}R^2$

C. $f\; is\;one\;to\;one\;on\;\mathbb{}R^2$

D. $for \;any\;a\in\mathbb{}R^2/\{(0,0)\}, f\;is\;one\;to\;one\;on\;some\;neighbourhood\;of a$

**My attempt**:$(Df)(a)=\bigtriangledown f(a).$ So, option (2) is correct. can u any help me for other options

Comment: The derivate is $Dz^2=2z$

Comment: correct options are A,B,D ,please let me know whether they are correct;I shall post an answer if it is so

Comment: @Amartya..Yes you are right please post your answers